# emacs: Close all window except treemacs

Tags: emacs, project-explorer

In Emacs when I open a file from treemacs, it opens it in a new frame by splitting the window.
I use C-x 1 to close all other frames and keep the selected frame open.

This also closes the Treemacs frame, I want the Emacs frame to remain open on C-x 1. Can this be done?

Treemacs: https://github.com/Alexander-Miller/treemacs

Comment: Frames or windows? Move to the window you want to keep (`C-x o` etc.), before using `C-x 1`.

Comment: Nope, I don't want to do that, I want to keep one of the frames fixed. The Treemacs window is the project explorer window that I want to keep open.

Comment: My crystal ball whispers that you are saying "window" when you mean "frame", and vice versa. But it's been wrong before...

Comment: My apologies, your are correct its windows, as mentioned here https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13583/whats-the-difference-between-a-buffer-a-file-a-window-and-a-frame